# css background image is not displaying

Tags: html, css

so far I was trying to display a background image using css however, the image is not showing up on the screen.

this is what I did so far:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './LoginScreen.css';


const LoginScreen = ()=>{
    return (
        <div className="container">
           
        </div>
    )
}


export default LoginScreen;
```

```css
*,*::before,*::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


.container {
    background-image: url("../../Images/online_auction.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and for my folder structure I have:
Images -->online_auction.jpg
and Screens -->LoginScreen --->LoginScreen.js + LoginSCreen.css

Comment: image url's in a stylesheet are relative to the stylesheet ... looks like you only need one `..`

Comment: CSS ends up as-is in the browser; the path needs to work as part of a URL, it cannot reference the project's file system directly. Move the image into `public/Images/` and use `"/Images/online_auction.jpg"` as url

Comment: This is not related to react particularly; try to debug your code on a simple HTML page. Then move it to your react app.
You have to define the width and height for your DIV tag (basic knowledge of HTML/CSS is needed to fix this issue)

Answer (score 1):

Add some content in container section or set height and width property to the container.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the browser devtools what the actual problem here is because it can be multiple things. First thing could be that the route is incorrect, if you select the div element in devtools you can hover over the url you provide in the css and it should show you the image if the route is correct. Or you can click on it and if it opens the image in a new tab everything is correct if not you have a wrong path to the image.

Second thing is you don't have any actual content in the div so the element has a width/height of 0px/0px. Since you are setting the image as a **background** you need to have actual space where that background can appear. I would suggest hardcoding some width and height values until you are sure the image is loading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you must adjust width class container if want to see `background-image` in class container, if you want to see `background-image` your page, you can write in tag body don't write in tag class.

or your address is not found maybe you can change:

```css
background-image: url(".../Images/online_auction.jpg");
```